# tuple to be locked was already moved to another partition due to concurrent update

Tags: postgresql

We have a table partitioned by value of boolean type (active = true or false). Sometimes when concurrent updates happen we catch:

```
ERROR: tuple to be locked was already moved to another partition due to concurrent update
```

AFAIU this is normal behaviour coz by the moment of update another update could happen and an entry (ies) had been moved to another partition.

I could find the only descriptive article about that:
https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/row-movement-across-postgresql-partitions-made-easy

From the ACID point of view the transaction has been rolled back and it has to be safe to retry and I want to implement it at the library's level. Is it really safe to do? (Especially from the possible side-effects like from triggers execution).

PostgreSQL 12.8